# Chrome/Webkit audio tag bug?

Tags: audio, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to get HTML5's audio tag to work in Chrome. The following code works flawlessly in Firefox, any ideas why it isn't working in Webkit?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function init(){
     audio = new Audio("chat.ogg");
     audio.play(); 
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
</body>
```

I should also note that I tried this with an mp3 as well. Regardless of what format, whenever .play() is called on audio, Chrome responds with "undefined".

Comment: Have you tried using the `<audio>` tag instead of JS?

Comment: I tried a different file, one that I didn't make and it seems to work. Not sure why the mp3s or ogg files I'm making with Audacity don't seem to be working. Weird that they work in Firefox and not Chrome too.

Comment: I think there might be a bug in Chrome. It appears that if the audio file is really short it won't play, but if it is long it plays fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bug in Chrome, possibly Webkit as well: 
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25972

Short audio files won't play.

Answer (score 2):

Try to host your audio file somewhere and try this:

```
audio = new Audio('http://www.yourhosting.com/chat.ogg');
audio.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the release version of Chrome? With the current dev build on Linux[1], I get the same behavior as FF 3.7 alpha (well, once I unblocked it with noscript) and SeaMonkey 2.0; that is, the Ogg file plays, although not even the default controls appear. If it is a bug in Chrome or Webkit, it is apparently fixed for the next version.

[1] Chrome: 5.0.342.1 (Official Build 40461) dev, Webkit: 533.2

Comment: Yep. I'm using 5.0.342.1 dev on OSX 10.5