# Simple html5 audio player works in browser but not in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

In the background.js file of my chrome extension i add this :

```
function loadSong(url) {
    var urlRadio = "mydomain.com";
    document.getElementById("player").src=urlRadio + url;
    document.getElementById("player").load();
    document.getElementById("player").play();
}
window.addEventListener('load', loadSong);
```

and in html :

```
<div>
    <audio tabindex="0" id="player" controls="controls">nothing</audio>
    <ul id="playlist">
        <li><a onclick="loadSong('one.mp3')">one</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="loadSong('two.mp3')">two</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I added background.js in the homepage , before  end tag and in the background part manifest of the chrome extension.

I want to use this player like a webpage and like a chrome extension, so when the code i put it here :

- "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null " at the
  loading in browser, but i can play songs
- "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null " at the loading in chrome extension, can't play songs

what's the problem ?

Comment: first guess out of the blue: The window load event is to early, the player isn't ready yet. `window.addEventListener('load', loadSong)` does not make any sense anyway since `url` is undefined. By the time you click a link however the player is readily rendered. Therefore it is working then.

Comment: Short audio files won't play. Bug in Chrome

[Check This][1] And [This][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037756/audio-not-loading-in-htmls-audio-tag
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422598/chrome-webkit-audio-tag-bug

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in ur script. First one is path of audio file and second in ur function call. Here is the sample u can try like this

Html:

```
<div>
<audio tabindex="0" id="player" controls="controls">nothing</audio>
<ul id="playlist">
    <li><a onclick="loadSong('one.mp3')">one</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="loadSong('two.mp3')">two</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Script:

```
function loadSong(url) {
var urlRadio = "path/";
document.getElementById("player").src=urlRadio + url;
document.getElementById("player").load();
document.getElementById("player").play();
}
window.addEventListener('load', loadSong("your audio file name example one.mp3"));
```

Your First error : Wrong path

```
var urlRadio = "mydomain.com";
document.getElementById("player").src=urlRadio + url;
```

in this case (urlRadio + url) the src will become like (mydomain.comone.mp3) this is wrong path it has to be like mydomain.com/one.mp3 .

Your Second error : Function call without passing parameter

```
 window.addEventListener('load', loadSong);
```

u have to pass the url value to loadSong function something like this loadSong("one.mp3")